# join in XArray akin to Pandas

Tags: python-xarray

Does xarray mean to avoid traditional table joins that Pandas does easily, or am I just not getting it? Here's a simple example with a "left" dataset (`ds`) and a "right" dataset (`other`) that I'd like to merge in a left join:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset({"a": ("index", list("xyzxyzxy"))})
other = xr.Dataset({"a": list("xz"), "b": ("a", [1, 2])})
```

On trying `ds.merge(other)`, xarray suggests it needs more information, but how do I tell it that "a" should not be a coordinate in the result?

```
MergeError: unable to determine if these variables should be coordinates or not in the merged result: {'a'}
```

The desired result is what I achieve with a diversion through Pandas:

```
>>> ds = ds.to_dataframe()
>>> other = other.to_dataframe()
>>> ds.join(other, on="a").to_xarray()
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (index: 8)
Coordinates:
  * index    (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Data variables:
    a        (index) object 'x' 'y' 'z' 'x' 'y' 'z' 'x' 'y'
    b        (index) float64 1.0 nan 2.0 1.0 nan 2.0 1.0 nan
```

**Unaccepted Answers**

```
>>> ds.set_coords("a").merge(other)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 2)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U1 'x' 'z'
Data variables:
    b        (a) int64 1 2
```

```
>>> ds.set_coords("a").merge(other, join="left")
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 2)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U1 'x' 'z'
Data variables:
    b        (a) int64 1 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does xarray mean to avoid traditional table joins that Pandas does easily, or am I just not getting it?

Using Pandas seems to be the only way to do this, at present. Unclear whether xarray plans not to implement this kind of join.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a coordinate variable in `other` but a data variable in `ds`.

```
>>> ds

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (index: 8)
Dimensions without coordinates: index
Data variables:
    a        (index) <U1 'x' 'y' 'z' 'x' 'y' 'z' 'x' 'y'

>>> other

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 2)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U1 'x' 'z'
Data variables:
    b        (a) int64 1 2
```

The solution is to explicitly make `a` a coordinate variable in `ds`. We should update the error message to suggest this solution

```
>>> ds.set_coords("a").merge(other)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 2)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U1 'x' 'z'
Data variables:
    b        (a) int64 1 2
```

Comment: That result is not a left join. Compare to the Pandas solution I gave, which keeps "index" as the dimension.

Comment: @ian does adding `.merge(other, join='left')` give you what you need?

Comment: @Maximilian, `join='left'` has no effect. I'd expect it would ... do you think it's a bug?

Comment: No, I didn't look through the example in enough detail but thought it was worth suggesting. To the extent you can add into the question the outputs you get, that would make it easier to see the actual vs. expected diff.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this actually. Pandas is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

a many to one merge can be implemented as detailed here by the user `dcherian`: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4766#issuecomment-754780927

I believe there is a slight typo in his answer however -- I used `z.sel(y=y, drop=True)` rather than `z.sel(x=y, drop=True)`.